# count all posts in table "posts" regarding users from table "users"

Tags: php, mysql

two tables - `posts` and `users`
column `posts.user` is matching with `users.id`.
I want to count all posts from all users, this way:

```
user1 5
user2 3
user3 9
```

... and so on meaning that `user1` from `users` has 5 instances from `posts`... etc.

```
$items = '';
$sql = "select users.name, posts.user from users inner join posts on users.id = posts.user";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   $count = $stmt->rowCount();
   $items .= "<div><span class='spanuser'>" . $row['name'] . "</span> <span class='spancount'>" . $count . "</span></div>";
    }
    echo $items;
```

**result**

```
user1 74 // 74 is total number of `posts` rows  
user2 74  
user3 74  
... all users - 74
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with `LEFT JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(p.id) AS `count`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user
GROUP BY u.name;
```

This will give you the desired output.

**Update**

As per our discussion, to get the count for today, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(p.id) AS `count`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user
WHERE DATE(datetime) = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY u.name;
```

Similarly, you can use `BETWEEN` operator to get the same count for a date range, e.g., for last 7 days, you can use this:

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(p.id) AS `count`
FROM users u LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user
WHERE DATE(datetime) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY u.name;
```

Also, you need to update the `php` to use the `count` returned by the query and not `rowCount`, e.g.:

```
$items .= "<div><span class='spanuser'>" . $row['name'] . "</span> <span class='spancount'>" . $row['count'] . "</span></div>";
```

Comment: @bonaca updated the answer, can you try it and add the error message if you still get syntax error?

Comment: There is no syntax error but `unefined index name...` message.

Comment: +Darshan, it's too complicated, I have additional problems, could we go to chat, pls

Comment: Sure.. We can discuss over chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way using `Count()`

```
$items = '';
$sql = "SELECT u.name,COUNT(p.user) as pCount FROM users u INNER JOIN posts p on u.id = p.user GROUP BY u.name";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $items .= "<div><span class='spanuser'>" . $row['name'] . "</span> <span class='spancount'>" . $row['pCount'] . "</span></div>";
}
echo $items;
```

Comment: Please note that this query won't return user records who do not have any posts.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by the user and count the number of posts, to get the final total row you want a `WITH ROLLUP` e.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(User,'TOTAL') AS Name, 
       Count(Post.ID) AS CountOfPosts
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Posts ON Posts.USer= Users.id
GROUP BY Users.id WITH ROLLUP
```

The "total" row will actually have a value of null so we use the `COALESCE` to change null into TOTAL

Comment: first I have `undefined column `Post.ID` and replaced with `posts.id`. Now I have `indefined index` name...

Comment: Make sure your PHP is looking at the columns i've aliased as Name and CountOfPosts

Answer (score 0):

Try use COUNT(). To count the `posts.user`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp